# Is there a standard name for this property of hash functions?

Tags: hash

A hash function $H$ operating on strings can have the following property:

Let $x$ be a string and $c$ a character. Given $H(x \cdot c)$ and $c$,
$H(x)$ can be determined uniquely (where $\cdot$ stands for concatenation).

Note that it may not be possible to determine $x$, only $H(x)$.

An example of such hash function is the "polynomial hash function"
$H(c_1 c_2 ... c_k) = a^{k-1} c_1 + a^{k-2} c_2 + ... + a c_{k-1} + c_k \; (mod \; P)$
for a prime $P$ and an integer $0 < a < P$. Given $H(x \cdot c)$ and $c$, $H(x)$
is given by $a^{-1} (H(x \cdot c) - c) \; (mod \; P)$.
Another function having this property is [Pearson hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_hashing).

Is there a standard name for hash functions having this property?

Comment: I'm not sure about that property specifically, but a very close one is "rolling hash". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash